# Jquery error and the correct loop index

Tags: jquery, ajax

Say I have this:

```
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "geocode-items.php",
        async: true,
        data: {  
            key: i
        },
        success: function( data )
        {
            // data returns the index I passed into the script with the data property.
        },
        error( a, b, c )
        {
            alert( i ); // this obviously won't work
        }
    });    
}
```

alert( i ); in the error section is not going to alert the correct index. Whereas in the success I can be passing back the key I put in to the geocode-items.php script, I can't pass anything back in the error section.

Do you know how to reference the original data sent through the request when firing the error method?

something like this.data.key? so I can report back an error for the specific object I'm stuck on? Rather than having to write some generic "there was an error code but I don't know where"

Comment: Why don't you make 1 AJAX request with the data of the 10 items in it, then dissect the return value, rather than firing off 10 requests, which will likely clog the browser for a short time?

Comment: ah geocode limits for google api. not relevant. but thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should read something about the scopes of javascript and about closures.
the value `i`is the same for each error callback in your case and because ajax is async the `i` is 10 for all of them.

javascript only has functions based scopes and no block based scopes.
What you can do is create an anonymous function where you pass your value to `(function(param1) { } )(value)` this function is called immediately. the parameters of the functions are then bound to that function call.

```
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    (function(idx) {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "geocode-items.php",
           async: true,
           data: {  
               key: idx
           },
           success: function( data )
           {
               // data returns the index I passed into the script with the data property.
           },
           error: function( a, b, c )
           {
               alert( idx ); // this obviously won't work
           }
        });
    })(i);   
}
```

Comment: Let me try this derp :D brb

Comment: I realise now this is like a c++ function pointer, please keep explaining though, it's very helpful to see how this works.. And p.s it does work. i'll mark your answer when I can! Thanks so so much!

Comment: What's happening is you are creating a function while passing in "i" as a parameter. This function now gives any sub functions scope to "i" because the variable i is copied as a new variable to the function rather than left as a pointer reference to the original variable declared in the original functions scope. Does that sound right?

Answer (score 0):

You can store `i` as a variable.

```
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    var index=i;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "geocode-items.php",
        async: true,
        data: {  
            key: i
        },
        success: function( data )
        {
            // data returns the index I passed into the script with the data property.
        },
        error( a, b, c )
        {
            alert( index ); // this obviously won't work
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: this would not work, because javascript has no block based scopes but only function based ones

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $.post("geocode-items.php", {key: i})
    .done(function (data) {
        // ...
    },
    .fail(function (i) {
        return function (a, b, c) {
            alert(i);
        };
    }(i));    
}
```

The point is that all Ajax callbacks are called asynchronously, i.e. they are invoked *after* the `for` loop has finished running. `i` will always be `9` in that case.

In case of the success callback, it knows its state from the server's response. It does not care what `i` is, therefore it works.

The error callback however does not have a response. It needs a closure to maintain the value of `i`.

---

That being said, it might not be the smartest thing in the first place to have virtually identical Ajax requests in a for loop. Combine them into one, send an array of values (JSON).

Comment: Google maps requires 10 geocode results per call per second and each request needs to be asynchronous so it doesn't hold up my application while trying to fetch the geocoded results. Sound better now? Thanks btw :)

Comment: @James I did not say anything against asynchronous - it's the only way to do HTTP requests in JS. If you are just looking for a way to synchronize your 10 requests then there is a nicer way to do it than keeping an `i` variable. Tell me if you want to know how.

Comment: Oh certainly.

So at the moment, I have a large amount of data that requires geocoding in google maps. I start a loop off for 10 bits of data that needs to be geocoded, I send that 10 bits of data off into PHP that runs the server side geocoding script and returns the results for that data... Whilst that Is happening, I have waited a second from the first call and then sent off another 10 bits of data to be geocoded. This is because google maps api only allows 10 geocodes per second. I use asynchronous code (ajax) to avoid having to sleep PHP code that geocodes and to allow a loading bar too.

Comment: any ideas on how this can be improved upon? It's working really nicely at the moment! but if you can think of a cleaner way, i'll certainly change my code :D

Comment: If it's working nicely, don't change it. I was about to suggest [jQuery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to handle your multiple concurrent requests, but on second thought the benefit might not be all that great for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

try using the jqXHR property

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

put the index property 'i' in the jqXHR before making ajax call using beforeSend event or ajaxSend() method

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/